# how for create double loop in javascript with if condition

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
for (var o = 1; o <= 10000; o++) {
    alert("also result "+o)
for (var p = 1; p <= 10000; p++) {
    alert("result "+p)
    if (p % 11 == 0) {
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

i want to result like this

> result 1  also result 1

> result 2  also result 1

> result 3  also result 1

> result 4  also result 1

> result 5  also result 1

> result 6  also result 1

> result 7  also result 1

> result 8  also result 1

> result 9  also result 1

> result 10 also result 1

> result 11 also result 2

> result 12 also result 2

> result 13 also result 2

> result 14 also result 2

> result 15 also result 2

> result 16 also result 2

> result 17 also result 2

> result 18 also result 2

> result 19 also result 2

> result 20 also result 2

> result 21 also result 3

> result 22 also result 3

> result 23 also result 3

> result 24 also result 3

> result 25 also result 3

> result 26 also result 3

> result 27 also result 3

> result 28 also result 3

> result 29 also result 3

> result 30 also result 3

how to create loop in javascript,,please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This task can be solved without nested loops

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
  console.log(`result ${i} also result ${Math.floor((i - 1) / 10) + 1}`)
}
```